# PhantomData use case

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand phantomData in rust, I have a Foo struct wrap around a raw pointer, and  I tell the compiler that Foo can not outlive 'a, so I trying to prevent the value of property v being dropped before Foo, but I found it doesn't work, when String s can be dropped before f. did I misunderstood something?

```rust
struct Foo<'a, T: 'a> {  // I say that T is valid over lifetime 'a
    pub v: *mut T,
    _mark: PhantomData<&'a T>
}

fn main() {
    let mut s = String::from("hello");
    let f = Foo {
        v: &mut s,
        _mark: PhantomData,
    };
    drop(s);  
    drop(f);
}
```

and I found I can even use the pointer to s after s was dropped like this

```rust
 let mut s = String::from("hello");
 let f = Foo {
     v: &mut s,
     _mark: PhantomData,
 };
 drop(s);
 let a = unsafe {&*f.v};
 println!("{}", a);
```

Comment: This is basically the example given in the rustdoc. I'm quite surprised that it does not work and allows for 'use after free'

Comment: @SvetlinZarev yes, that confuse me

Comment: How should the compiler know that `'a` is in any way related to `s`, since you're using the language feature that explicitly erases any such relationship?

Comment: @trentcl thanks, I was trying to understand the example from rust doc https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html, and it is said "This also in turn requires the annotation T: 'a, indicating that any references in T are valid over the lifetime 'a.", so my understanding is that I told that Foo has a generic type T and generic lifetime 'a, in this example where T is String and the life time of s is 'a ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the comments, I presume the confusion arises from `T: 'a` and lifetime inference. The [meaning of `T: 'a`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/scope/lifetime/lifetime_bounds.html) is that any lifetime parameters of `T` are as long as `'a`. For a type `T` like `String`, there are no lifetime parameters, so this is true for any value of `'a` including `'static`.

Roughly speaking, `T: 'a` means that you can hold onto a value of type `T` as long as `'a`. It must either own its data (like `String`) or any references it contains must live long enough.

Therefore when you initialize `f`:

```
let f = Foo {
    v: &mut s,
    _mark: PhantomData,
};
```

`T` can be inferred to be `String`, but any value of `'a` is valid. There is no constraint on the lifetime.

One has to tell the compiler in some way that the lifetime of the initializing reference (which we are converting into a lifetime-less pointer before initializing `Foo`) is connected to the lifetime we want to use on `Foo`. For example:

```
impl<'a, T: 'a> Foo<'a, T> {
    // the input lifetime and the output lifetime are the same
    fn new(t: &'a mut T) -> Foo<'a, T> {
        Foo {
            v: t,
            _mark: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

let f = Foo::new(&mut s);
```