# why PhantomData<T> is added to the struct, but the code still compile and has a use-after-free bug

Tags: rust

I write the following code (code 1) after reading the [Nomicon](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/phantom-data.html). I think it should not compile. But actually, it compiles and has a use-after-free bug.
The `PhantomData<T>` should tell that the compiler that the `World` owns the `T`, so it will call the destructor of `T`. But in the following code, the last `ptr` does not outlive `world` and will drop before the `world`, a UAF happens.

```
// code 1: compile but has UAF
use std::ptr;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

use std::fmt::Debug;
impl<T:Debug> Drop for World<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
       unsafe{
        println!("I was only {:?} days from retirement!", ptr::read(self.ptr));
       }
    }
}

struct World<T:Debug> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
fn main() {
    let mut v = 8usize;
    let mut world = World {
        ptr: &mut v as *mut usize,
        _marker: PhantomData
    };
    let mut v = 99usize;
    world.ptr = &mut v as *mut usize;
}
```

The sentences leads to my confusion is

> In order to tell dropck that we do own values of type T, and therefore may drop some T's when we drop, we must add an extra PhantomData saying exactly that:

```
use std::marker;

struct Vec<T> {
    data: *const T, // *const for variance!
    len: usize,
    cap: usize,
    _marker: marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
```

The following code (code 2) will compile and has UAF.
But uncomment the `PhantomData<T>` will not compile (see the code 3).

```
// code 2: compile and has UAF
#![feature(dropck_eyepatch)]
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ptr;
struct MyBox<T> {
    pub raw: *mut T,
    //_marker: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    fn new(x: T) -> MyBox<T> {
        Self {
            raw: Box::into_raw(Box::new(x)),
           // _marker: PhantomData
        }
    }
}
unsafe impl<#[may_dangle] T> Drop for MyBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(self.raw);
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar<T: Debug>(T);

impl<T: Debug> Drop for Bar<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _b;
    let x = "hell".to_owned();
    _b = MyBox::new(Bar(&x));
}
```

Code 3

```
// code 3: does not compile becuase PhantomData<T>
#![feature(dropck_eyepatch)]
use std::fmt::Debug;
use std::marker::PhantomData;
use std::ptr;
struct MyBox<T> {
    pub raw: *mut T,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>
}

impl<T> MyBox<T> {
    fn new(x: T) -> MyBox<T> {
        Self {
            raw: Box::into_raw(Box::new(x)),
            _marker: PhantomData
        }
    }
}
unsafe impl<#[may_dangle] T> Drop for MyBox<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        unsafe {
            Box::from_raw(self.raw);
        }
    }
}

#[derive(Debug)]
struct Bar<T: Debug>(T);

impl<T: Debug> Drop for Bar<T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
        println!("{:?}", self.0);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let _b;
    let x = "hell".to_owned();
    _b = MyBox::new(Bar(&x));
}
```

Code 4: why the following code can compile with UAF

```
use std::ptr;
use std::marker::PhantomData;

use std::fmt::Debug;
impl<'a, T:Debug> Drop for World<'a, T> {
    fn drop(&mut self) {
       unsafe{
        println!("I was only {:?} days from retirement!", ptr::read(self.ptr));
       }
    }
}

struct World<'a, T:Debug> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a mut T>,
}
fn main() {

    let mut v = 8usize;
    let mut world = World {
        ptr: &mut v as *mut usize,
        _marker: PhantomData
    };
    let mut v = 99usize;
    world.ptr = &mut v as *mut usize;
}
```

Comment: That is not true, the phantomdata do not owns the T, you are not actually moving it into the World struct, hence it can still live after. Your `World` struct only has a pointer to such data. nothing else.

Comment: @Netwave But the Nomicon says it does.
```
In order to tell dropck that we do own values of type T, and therefore may drop some T's when we drop, we must add an extra PhantomData saying exactly that:

```

use std::marker;

struct Vec<T> {
    data: *const T, // *const for variance!
    len: usize,
    cap: usize,
    _marker: marker::PhantomData<T>,
}
```

Comment: Operative word "**may**". `World` can't possibly know that it owns `ptr` and that it should drop it. You must do that manually. The PhantomData marker is descriptive, not prescriptive.

Comment: Also note that "may drop some T's" does not mean "will prolong some T's so they can be dropped later".

Answer (score 1):

This definition says to treat `World` *as if* it owns a `T`. The pointer should point to something `World` manages:

```
struct World<T:Debug> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

This use creates a `World` where the pointer points to something *not* owned by  `world`. It is instead *as if* it contained a reference:

```
    let mut v = 8usize;
    let mut world = World {
        ptr: &mut v as *mut usize,
        _marker: PhantomData
    };
```

These are in conflict. If you want referential behavior, define `World` with a reference:

```
struct World<'a, T:Debug> {
    ptr: *mut T,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a mut T>,
}
```

If you want owning behavior, the construction must create an owned version:

```
    let mut v = 8usize;
    let mut world = World {
        ptr: Box::into_raw(Box::new(v)) as *mut usize,
        _marker: PhantomData
    };
```

> The PhantomData should tell that the compiler that the World owns the T, so it will call the destructor of T.

`PhantomData<T>` tells the compiler to treat `World` as if it owns a `T` and that *`World`* will call the destructor of `T`.

In code #2/#3:

```
fn main() {
    let _b;
    let x = "hell".to_owned();
    _b = MyBox::new(Bar(&x));
}
```

Without the `PhantomData`, the borrow checker cannot know the relationship of `MyBox<T>` and `T`, so it compiles. With the `PhantomData`, you have an owning structure, and it fails to compile because `x` is dropped before `_b`. I'm not sure if the confusion comes from the drop ordering, due to the let and later initialization, or from the the behavior of `may_dangle` which only applies to inspecting `T`, [but `T` may still inspect its contents on drop](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1327-dropck-param-eyepatch.md).

Code #4 compiles with UAF because the lifetime of the initializer isn't the one inferred for `World`. The lifetime of the referred-to data must be captured. I wrote an answer to a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67759595/phantomdata-use-case/67762508#67762508).

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. But even I use the referential behavior, the code still compiles and has UAF. I have added the `code 3` which will not compile after adding the `PhantomData<T>`. Could you take a look to see what's the difference between `code 1` and `code 2`, why `code 1` compile with UAF but `code 3` does not compile?

Comment: I have added the `code 4` that uses the referential behavior but still can compile with UAF.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. It solves parts of my doubts so I upvote your answer. I will come back later if I can digest your full information and decide it is the accepted answer. Thanks!